# How to update specific object property in React state

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state, immutability

I'm trying to make my code more concise and therefore removed all of these from separate useState hooks and put them into one. But I'm now trying to update the visible property of the objects based on a toggle state. I've attempted I've looked through different answers about immutable state / mapping through object etc. But it's confusing me even more. What do I put in between my function to change state on toggle change?

```
const [columnsVisible, setColumnsVisible] = useState({
    column1: { visible: true },
    column2: { visible: true },
    column3: { visible: true },
    column4: { visible: true },
  });

const changeColumnVisibility = () => {

}

return(
{columnsVisible.column1.visible &&
                         (
                          <Column
                            <>
                              {toOrderState.map((job, index) => (
                                <JobCard
                                  job_number={job.jobNumber}
                                  time={job.time}
                                />
                              ))}
                            </>
                          />
                        )}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve immutability is by using [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). As an example:

```
const myObject = { a: 1, b: 'some text', c: true };
const myCopy = { ...myObject };
```

results in `myCopy` being identical to `myObject` but changing `myCopy` (e.g. `myCopy.a = 2`) will *not* change `myObject`.

Now extend that so that `myObject` has more *complex stuff* in it instead of just an integer or a boolean.

```
const myObject = { a: { visible: true, sorted: 'ASC' } };
const myCopy = { ...myObject };
```

The thing here is that if you change `myCopy`'s `visible` (for example, `myCopy.a.visible = false`) you will be changing `myObject` (`myObject.a.visible` will also be `false` even though you haven't explicitly changed `myObject`).

The reason for the above is that the Spread operator is *shallow*; so when you are making a copy of `a` you really are making a copy of the reference to the original `a` (`{ visible: true, sorted: 'DESC' }`). But guess what, you can use the Spread operator for copying `a`.

```
const myObject = { a: { visible: true, sorted: 'ASC' } };
const myCopy = { a: { ...myObject.a } };
```

Before addressing specific question, there is one more interesting thing about the Spread operator... you can overwrite some of the copied values simply by adding a key to the new object

```
const myObject = { a: 1, b: 'some text', c: true };
const myCopy = { ...myObject, a: 2 };
```

with the above, `myCopy.a` will be `2` rather than `1.

So now think about what needs to change when `changeColumnVisibility` is called... you want to change one of the column details but not the others

```
const [columnsVisible, setColumnsVisible] = useState({
    column1: { visible: true },
    column2: { visible: true },
    column3: { visible: true },
    column4: { visible: true },
  });

// columnName is either `'column1'`, `'column2'`, ...
const changeColumnVisibility = (columnName) => {
  setColumnsVisible((currentColumnsVisible) => {
    const isVisible = currentColumnsVisible[columnName].visible;
    return {
      ...currentColumnsVisible,
      [columnName]: { ...currentColumnsVisible[columnName], visible: !isVisible }
    };
  });
}
```

`[columnName]` is important to be used so that you actually end up setting `column1` or `column2` or whatever rather than adding an attribute called `columnName`.

The final thing to call out from the snippet is that I'm using `setColumnsVisible` with a callback to ensure that the values are changed correctly rather than using `columnsVisible` directly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much for the indepth explanation. I'm currently getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visible')